# Weird new users in Joomla user group "Administrator"

Tags: security, joomla

I noticed today that 30 people or so registered to my Joomla site (I don't expose a registration/login form), most of them appear to be spammers/bots, somehow they must've found a way to register via hidden URLs. All of these users are disabled (the default) but what's bothering me is that some of these users are in the group **`Administrator`**.

Notably there are the users with emails `assistent@rootfest.net`, `bagiteja@rootfest.net` or `dazofaw3@mail.ru`. If you google for these addresses, you can [find](http://www.suin.edu.sd/index.php/users) a [bunch](http://www.storagemojo.nl/index.php/lijst/9-sudouser) of sites - they seem to be other Joomla installations that have been hacked or something like that?

I am really not sure what to make out of this. The `Enabled` and `Activated` checkboxes in the Joomla admin panel are both disabled for all these, i.e. show red crosses. Can these users still do harm in any way? Should I be worried?

I wasn't sure whether to post this here, in the Joomla SE or security SE. Hope it's ok here.

Answer (score 1):

A hacker has access to your Joomla instance with administrative rights, you should be worried: **Your site is compromised**.

This is probably due to not keeping the site with the latest updates, which Joomla has several security issues.

Also a new exploit in [PHPmailer](http://thehackernews.com/2016/12/phpmailer-security.html) (Joomla's default) has been discovered recently that makes unpatched versions vulnerable.

You should use **Two Factor Authentication**, Joomla already supports it since J!3.2, check all your files for modifications and update to the latest version urgently.

Comment: `A hacker has access to your Joomla instance with administrative rights` I'm curious how you come to this conclusion, as the accounts are disabled and deactivated. I'd like to understand what's going on.

Comment: Users appeared from nowhere in your Administrative group, anything can happen from there. I won't be so sure that they can't do anything more just by being disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Your installation seems to be hacked. People can programmatically apply new users to hacked sites, even sites are deactivated.

- Backup your database.
- Setup a folder protect for your Joomla installation folder with htpassword, if you want to clean it out.
- Find compromised/changed files, using Google search or instructions like [this](https://www.bluebridgedev.com/hacked-joomla-files) or [that](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/hacks/clean-up-code-injection-attack).
- replace them with not-compromised files
- Or delete the installation folder.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely Joomla has not been patched to the latest version.

For example, [a recent vulnerability](https://developer.joomla.org/security-centre/664-20161201-core-elevated-privileges.html) fixed in the Joomla 3.6.5 update "allows for existing user accounts to be modified; to include resetting their username, password, and user group assignments".

I recommend updating Joomla and third party extensions to the latest versions and deleting all suspect accounts.

It might also be prudent to run a commercial scanning service over the website such as [myjoomla.com](http://myjoomla.com) or [sucuri.net](http://sucuri.net) to check for malicious files.